# GTK3 sometimes ignores gtk_widget_queue_draw when repeated too quickly?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have an application which does some simulation, and renders the result.  Because the render can sometimes be very slow, I separated it into another thread, and the main thread calls `gtk_widget_queue_draw` once it's ready.  If it's not finished drawing yet, the extra requests get discarded (since `queue_draw` only invalidates it, and it's impossible to be "more" invalid).

The result is that with large complicated systems, simulation maxes out a thread, and render maxes out another thread, and everything works.

I just ran into a different problem, and I don't see why it's happening:  A sufficiently simple simulation and render (6 5-point lines) causes it to break.

The first few (I've seen everywhere from around 60 to 400) steps render fine (in a fraction of a second), until one step renders twice.  After that, it ignores the `queue_draw`, until I do something like drag a window over the render window, after which it restarts (until it breaks again).

If I artificially slow down the requests (`usleep(10000)` is around enough), this does not happen.

This is a completely unacceptable solution however, because the process of displaying is not allowed to interfere with the normal simulation thread (No delays, no mutexes, etc. etc.).  I need a solution that makes the render thread do "as well as possible", given that it is working with volatile data.  It does not have to be perfectly accurate--I really don't care if a frame renders a little wrong (half of frame i, half of i+1 is fine), as long as it does render.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is the "main thread" the event loop thread?  Also, there's a bunch of "it"s in the first paragraph that are so numerous as to be confusing, could you clarify?

Comment: The event loop is pushed to a secondary thread `pthread_create(&renderThread,NULL,gtk_main_wrapper,NULL);`, where `void* gtk_main_wrapper() {
        gtk_main();
        return NULL;
}`.  The main thread throws a `queue_draw` whenever it finishes a step, under the assumption that extra requests aren't a problem.

Comment: Per @liberforce, add locking.  See here: http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/andrew/software/gnome-desktop/gtk-thread-awareness

Comment: hmm.. the issue is that the I need a non-blocking way of telling the GUI to redraw itself.  IIRC when I had the lock, it synced the two threads, which is unacceptable.

Comment: The lock is held during a draw event, so that makes sense.  You will probably need to double buffer (in a seperate thread slow render into pixmap and draw that on updates) to avoid spending too much time in the draw handler. You'll have to step the render some other way though. And you still need to synchronize gdk calls.

Comment: Did you ever find an acceptable solution for this zebediah49? I'm having the same problem, and the locking functions mentioned by ergosys have been deprecated in GTK+3.6 so I am not sure what I am supposed to use.

Comment: @DanielGibbs I have not really.  The best I could come up with is a `if ( time=getTime() < lastTime+MIN_INTERVAL) { gtk_widget_queue_draw(myWidget); lastTime=time;}` wrapper to ensure that it is not called more than, say, every 10 ms (100fps).  It's a workaround, not a solution--but it more or less works.

Comment: Gdk drawing can be starved by higher priority event sources such as timeouts or idle functions. If you're using those (e.g. through g_timeout_add() or g_idle_add()), they need to either have a lower priority than drawing (GDK_PRIORITY_REDRAW = 120; c.f. G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT = 100) or to fire less often.

Answer (score 3):

You are having a race condition.

**Since GTK3.6**, you need to call `gtk_widget_queue_draw` like this:

```
g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)gtk_widget_queue_draw,(void*)window);
```

or like this:

```
gdk_threads_add_idle((GSourceFunc)gtk_widget_queue_draw,(void*)window);
```

where window is the `GtkWidget*` you want to draw.

Use the `gdk_threads_add_idle` if you're not sure whether libraries or code used by your app use the deprecated (since 3.6) `gdk_threads_enter` and `gdk_threads_leave` functions.

See: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.description

**Before GTK3.6**, `gdk_threads_enter` and `gdk_threads_leave` had to be used to acquire the lock for GTK calls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you locked UI calls in the threads with gdk_threads_enter/gdk_threads_leave ?
Maybe adding a code sample would help too...